# Ubuntu bash telling me to upgrade packages that are already upgraded

Tags: ubuntu, bash, bash-scripting

Why is Ubuntu/bash telling me to upgrade packages that are already updated? I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows Subsystem for Linux running on Win10 2004.

[image]

How can I make it happy?

Comment: It appears you have multiple versions of `pip`, `numpy`, and `scipy` installed.  Tensorflow is detecting an out of date package while the system packages are current.

Comment: How can i remove the old versions and force this build process (Tacotron-2) to find the latest verions? (Apologies, I'm a linux noob.)

Comment: Specifically, TensorFlow is using a venv (virtual environment) and your installation within that virtual environment is out of date.  [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).  The solution is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644402/i-keep-getting-a-message-to-upgrade-pip)

Comment: I read your links, but I'm not understanding what exact commands I would need to run. Can you point me in a direction?

Comment: I don't have your system in front of me.  Your screenshot isn't that helpful.  I would try and simply uninstall TensorFlow, or follow the recommended configuration, if you are already not using a virtual environment.  *You will have to find the location of the duplicate package yourself.*

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Synaptic Package Manager](https://itsfoss.com/synaptic-package-manager/) for an easy-to-interpret GUI.

[image: Synaptic Pkg Mgr]

It can show you all packages, sort them by status, name, etc., enable you to easily install and uninstall packages and related groups of packages, identify those needing to be updated and those which may safely be removed, and so on.

The Synaptic Package Manager should have been installed in Ubuntu by default, but can [easily be added](https://techpiezo.com/linux/install-synaptic-package-manager-in-ubuntu/) in Terminal:

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

You can uninstall unneeded packages that are present in newer versions, and update anything that is out-of-date.

Comment: SPM sounds great, but I'm running Ubuntu inside Windows Subsystem for Linux, so it's just bash and nothing else. Will that still work?

Comment: It should... Give it a try; it should install with that one line in Termial.

Comment: Installed. How do I run it? (sorry I'm a noob at linux)

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding. As previously mentionied, I'm not running linux. I'm running Windows 10, and inside that a bash command shell, which is WSL Ubuntu. There is no UI. Hitting the windows key while in this bash shell does nothing but pop open the windows Start Menu.